# Is it possible to convert this for loop with a changing variable into a list comprehension?

Tags: python

```
for i in range(10):
    n += 1
    summary += n
```

Is it possible to convert this `for` loop into a list comprehension? I tried but it didn't come out right:

```
summary = [sum(n+1 for i in range(10))]
```

Comment: You can calculate n from i using the initial value of n (needs an adjustment).

Comment: Are you just trying to sum the integers between n and n+10? In that case, just do sum(range(n, n+10)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest method is to call sum directly on range:

```
summary = sum(range(n+1))
```

Which has linear complexity. If you want to do this for large numbers you can do constant complexity, using the partial sum of natural numbers: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1_%2B_2_%2B_3_%2B_4_%2B_%E2%8B%AF

```
summary = n*(n+1)/2
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are trying to do sum of n to n+10 you can try it 
`summary = sum([n+i for i in range(11)])`

Comment: Your answer is correct, but not optimal. The generation of a list (square brackets) is not required, and increases memory consumption. You are also making the assumption the `assumption == 0` before the loop, which is a fair one, but you need to mention it.